# tfs configuration : include user phone number from active directory

Tags: tfs

New to TFS configuration/manipulation and looking to be pointed in the right direction thanks.

Our bug reports are often posted with minimal information and its often necessary to call the creator to get clarification.  It would be beneficial if we could display the phone number alongside the creators name.  Is it possible to pull this info out of the directory ?

[image: TFS Screen Cap]

Comment: I would suggest that those folks should not be creating bugs! A bug is reproducible and defigned. You should use the Feedback tool for user reported things.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of a simple way of doing it, apart from writing code. I can think of these techniques:

1. pulling data from Active Directory and updating work items;
2. a custom control that query AD (via a REST web service) just in time

This latter can evolve to became a 2015 extension